# Export json response in e6

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I am trying to export a `response` from a fetch to be used globally in an app i am building, but i cant get it to work properly. It says that its a syntax `error` on the line where i am exporting.

**code:**

```
const URL = './dist/json/settings.json';
let ENV = null;

fetch(URL).then(res => res.json())
.then(data => {
  // console.log(data);
  ENV = data;
})
.catch(e => {
  console.log(e);
})

export ENV;
```

Module that i want to access the json in.

```
import AbstractModule from './AbstractModule'

class SummaryModule extends AbstractModule {
  constructor () {
    super()
    this.init()
  }

  init () {

  }
}

export default SummaryModule
```

Comment: just a side note, you'd better export the promise or function that returns promise

Comment: Sounds celver. How would one do that?

Comment: ^^^ `export default fetch(URL)`

Comment: Thanks, how can i then access the data from another module? how to import it properly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just add `export` to the declaration:

```
const URL = './dist/json/settings.json';
export let ENV = null; // <====

fetch(URL).then(res => res.json())
.then(data => {
  // console.log(data);
  ENV = data;
})
.catch(e => {
  console.log(e);
});
```

Or if you really want the export at the end (there's no need for it to be), you can use:

```
export { ENV };
```

---

**But**, since other modules may use the exported binding before it's been filled in, you might consider exporting the promise of the value instead of the value itself, so that they can use `then` (or `await`) to ensure they wait for the value to arrive:

```
const URL = './dist/json/settings.json';
export const envPromise = fetch(URL).then(res => res.json());
envPromise.catch(e => {
    console.log(e);
});
```

Note that I've moved the `catch` handler so that we're turning the original promise which may reject rather than the one created by `catch` which (as written) would convert rejection into a resolution with `undefined`. That's so modules consuming this module's `envPromise` also see rejections and can cope accordingly. Alternately, rethrow it:

```
const URL = './dist/json/settings.json';
export const envPromise = fetch(URL)
    .then(res => res.json())
    .catch(e => {
        console.log(e);
        throw e;
    });
```

You could leave the `catch` off entirely. If you did, at least one consumer of the module would need to have a `catch` or you'd get an "Unhandled rejection error" (eventually) if the fetch fails.

You'd then import and use it like this:

```
import { envPromise } from './themodule.js';
```

...and where you want to use it:

```
envPromise.then(env => {
    // ...use env...
});
```

You could also make it the default export instead:

```
export default fetch(/*...*/);
```

and change the import:

```
import anyNameIWantHere from './themodule.js';
// ...
anyNameIWantHere.then(env => {
    // ...use env...
});
```

Comment: Thanks, how would you go on doing that? (exporting the promise)

Comment: Your promise is : `fetch(URL).then(res => res.json())`. If you export that, you'll be able to use: myModule.then(env => {...});

Comment: @user2952238: I've added code showing how to do that.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder im jot sure i catch you here. I have added code in my question that represent the module i like to access the json in.

Comment: @user2952238: Added `import`s above.